# Spring Boot: OAuth2Credentials instance does not support refreshing the access token

Tags: spring-boot, google-oauth

I am using Spring Boot and I am getting this error message: `{"errors":["OAuth2Credentials instance does not support refreshing the access token. An instance with a new access token should be used, or a derived type that supports refreshing."]}`.

```
@GetMapping("/callback")
    public ResponseEntity<String> callback(@RequestParam(value = "code") String code) throws IOException {

        TokenResponse tokenResponse = authService.getTokenResponse(code, CALLBACK_URI);
        List<String> scopes = List.of("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");

        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.create(new AccessToken(tokenResponse.getAccessToken(), null));
        GoogleCredentials scopedCredential = credentials.createScoped(scopes);

        HttpRequestInitializer initializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(scopedCredential);
        Oauth2 oauth2 = new Oauth2.Builder(httpTransport, jacksonFactory, initializer)
                .setApplicationName("Test") // replace with your application name
                .build();

        Userinfo userinfo = oauth2.userinfo().get().execute();
        String email = userinfo.getEmail();
        System.out.println(email);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
```

The error pops up at this line of code: `Userinfo userinfo = oauth2.userinfo().get().execute();`.
I am trying to get the email of the user.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.
In my GoogleAuthService.java I had to add the userinfo.email scope to my `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow`.

```
 public String getAuthorizationUrl(String callbackUrl) {
        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                CalendarScopes.CALENDAR
        ));
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, jacksonFactory, googleClientSecrets, scopes)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        return flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(callbackUrl).build();
    }
```